# How to change position of a JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

I'm trying to use a timer to change the position of a JLabel, from one spot on my JPanel to another. I'm not sure if I could use say `.getLocation()`, then change only the horizontal x value, and finally use `.setLocation()` to effectively modify the JLabel. I've also used `.getBounds` and `.setBounds`, but am still unsure how I can obtain the old horizontal x value to change and reapply to the new x value.

The code I tried looks something like this, but neither is a valid way to change the position of the JLabel.

```
// mPos is an arraylist of JLabels to be moved.

for(int m = 0; m < mPos.size(); m++){
        mPos.get(m).setLocation(getLocation()-100);
    }
```

or

```
    for(int m = 0; m < mPos.size(); m++){
        mPos.get(m).setBounds(mPos.get(m).getBounds()-100);
    }
```

If I could just get the position of the horizontal x value I can change the position of the label.

Comment: Also when the timer fires my action Listener is what calls for the change of the horizontal x value. And that change of the x Value is always constant.

Comment: Please show a minimum working example demonstrating what you have tried.

Comment: Are you using `null` layout? There are a lots of Layout Managers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a similar example just so you can get the basic jest of it, try copy pasting this in a new class called "LabelPlay" and it should work fine.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


public class LabelPlay {

private JFrame frame;
private JLabel label;
private Random rand;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                LabelPlay window = new LabelPlay();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public LabelPlay() {
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 659, 518);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    label = new JLabel("YEEEHAH!");
    label.setBounds(101, 62, 54, 21);
    frame.getContentPane().add(label);

    JButton btnAction = new JButton("Action!");
    rand = new Random();
    btnAction.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            int a = rand.nextInt(90)+10;
            int b = rand.nextInt(90)+10;
            int c = rand.nextInt(640)+10;
            int d = rand.nextInt(500)+10;
            label.setBounds(a, b, c, d);                
        }
    });
    btnAction.setBounds(524, 427, 89, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnAction);

}
```

}

If you want this to happen in a loop at certain times, you can just put it in a loop and use Thread.sleep(amount of miliseconds) in the loop before you run the code.

Comment: This is a good example! I'll work around with it and see if I can make it work for multiple labels. I just want to save the height, width, and vertical y value of each label, only the x should change.

Comment: Well consider it a challenge and play around with it until you get the result you want it will be more gratifying in the end.

Comment: why are you using `null` layout? Will it work on different resolution on different Operating system.

Comment: I made it in like 2 minutes and didn't go into details... I just wanted to show him the basic jest of it so he can figure out the rest for himself.

Answer (score 2):

Try with [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) if you are looking for some animation.

Please have a look at [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Here is the sample code:

```
int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      //...Perform a task...
  }
};
new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```

Find a [Sample code here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html)

[image]

---

Sample code: (*Move Hello World message 10px horizontally left to right at interval of 200 ms*)

```
private int x = 10;
...
final JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawString("Hello World", x, 10);
    }
};

int delay = 200; // milliseconds
ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        x += 10;
        if (x > 100) {
            x = 10;
        }
        panel.repaint();
    }
};
new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a JLabel at position a, set it to visible, and another one at position b, setting it to not visible? After the timer is up, hide the first and show the second.

Comment: That would be a good idea that I havn't thought of. Unfortunately, the problem is I have multiple JLabels that have to move about 100 times. I could do that but it would be very time consuming and tedious. I'm looking for a way I can use a constant value to change the position of all my JLabels, using a loop to hit all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Are you planning on creating some moving imageIcon for some type of game? Or some label that moves pretty much everywhere ?
I would use an Absolute Layout and set Location manually everytime.

```
myPanel.setLayout(null);

// an initial point
int x = 100;
int y =100;

while (
    //some moving pattern
    x++;   // 1 pixel per loop
    y+=2;  // 2 pixels per loop
    myLabel.setLocation(x,y);
}
```

Comment: Never suggest `null` layout.